# How to initialize an array of 16-bit integers in ARM64?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

I'm trying to learn some assembly, specifically ARM64.

I'm trying to initialize an array of 16-bit integers to some fixed value (123).

Here's what I have:

```
.global _main
.align 2

_main:
  mov x0, #0               ; start with a 0-byte offset
  mov x1, #123             ; the value to set each 16-bit element to
  lsl x1, x1, #48          ; shift this value to the upper 16-bits of the register

  loop:
    str x1, [sp, x0]       ; store the full 64-bit register at some byte offset
    add x0, x0, #2         ; advance by two bytes (16-bits)
    cmp x0, #10            ; loop until we've written five 16-bit integers
    b.ne loop

  ldr x2, [sp]             ; load the first four 16-bit integers into x2
  ubfm x0, x2, #48, #63    ; set the exit status to the leftmost 16-bit integer
  mov x16, #1              ; system exit
  svc 0                    ; supervisor call
```

I'm expecting the exit status to be 123 but it's 0. I don't understand why.

If I comment out the last two lines of the loop the exit status is 123 which is correct.

Please could someone explain what's going on? Is it an alignment problem?

Thanks

Comment: You're not actually making space on the stack for this data, are you?  You're overwriting everything on the stack above your program.  The only reason it doesn't crash is that you exit instead of returning.  And even so, you're being lucky in that there actually are enough bytes of stack before you run off the top of it.

Comment: And make sure that your stack pointer is always aligned on a 16 bytes boundary, [this is required](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/using-the-stack-in-aarch32-and-aarch64). In your case, using `sub sp, sp, 16` before `loop:` and `add sp, sp, 16`  after `ldr x2, [sp] `should fix this issue - I guess. Good catch, I did not even notice because  I  only debugged the main code section in a QEMU machine.

Comment: You're right. In my attempt to make a minimal example I removed `sub sp, sp, #16` which was making room on the stack for the array. This definitely needs to stay in!

Comment: Oh, it occurs to me that even with `sub sp, sp, #16` I'd be writing two bytes above the end of the stack so `sp` should probably be moved down by `24` bytes.

Comment: @Frant: I posted that idea as an answer; I'll delete that comment since it's redundant now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are running your program on a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) `Aaarch64 system`, on a given loop iteration, you are overriding the bytes you had modified in the previous one:

You are actually writing the bytes:
`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7b` 
from: `sp + x0 + 0`
to: `sp + x0 + 7` at each iteration.

Initial conditions:

```
(gdb) p/x $sp
$3 = 0x40010000
(gdb) x/12xh 0x40010000
0x40010000:     0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000
0x40010010:     0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000

# initializing some memory to 0xff so that we may see what is going on
(gdb) set {unsigned long }(0x40010000) = 0xffffffffffffffff
(gdb) set {unsigned long }(0x40010008) = 0xffffffffffffffff
(gdb) set {unsigned long }(0x40010010) = 0xffffffffffffffff

(gdb) x/12xh 0x40010000
0x40010000:     0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff
0x40010010:     0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff
```

Before first loop:

```
(gdb) p/x$x1
$4 = 0x7b000000000000
```

Looping:

```
# pass #1, after str x1, [sp, x0]
(gdb) x/12xh 0x40010000
0x40010000:     0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x007b  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff
0x40010010:     0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff

# pass #2, after str x1, [sp, x0]
(gdb) x/12xh 0x40010000
0x40010000:     0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x007b  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff
0x40010010:     0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff

# pass #3, after str x1, [sp, x0]
(gdb) x/12xh 0x40010000
0x40010000:     0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x007b  0xffff  0xffff
0x40010010:     0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff

# pass #4, after str x1, [sp, x0]
0x40010000:     0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x007b  0xffff
0x40010010:     0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff

# pass #5, after str x1, [sp, x0]
(gdb) x/12xh 0x40010000
0x40010000:     0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x007b
0x40010010:     0xffff  0xffff  0xffff  0xffff

# after ldr x2, [sp]:
(gdb) p/x $sp
$2 = 0x40010000
(gdb) p/x $x2
$3 = 0x0
(gdb)
```

Your program would work if you were not shifting the value in `x1`, by commenting-out `lsl x1, x1, #48`:

```
# after ldr x2, [sp]
(gdb) x/12xh 0x40010000
0x40010000:     0x007b  0x007b  0x007b  0x007b  0x007b  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000
0x40010010:     0x0000  0x0000  0x0000  0x0000
(gdb) p/x $x2
$1 = 0x7b007b007b007b
(gdb)
```

This being said, this would probably better to use the [strh](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100076/0100/a64-instruction-set-reference/a64-data-transfer-instructions/strh--register-) instruction, so that you would avoid writing more bytes than you should, i.e. 16 instead of 2, at each iteration of your loop.

Bottom line, on a little-endian system, the constant `0x0000000000007b` will be stored in memory (ascending addresses) as `7b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`, and the constant `0x7b00000000000000` will be stored as `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7b`.

Because of the shifting you do, you are storing `0x7b00000000000000`, not `0x0000000000007b`, into memory.

Comment: I see! I hadn't understood endianness. I was imagining the 64-bit number in memory in the same way I'd write it on paper with the most significant bit on the left. I was also imagining memory going left to right and so mistakenly thought I needed to left shift by 48 bits to avoid overwriting the 16-bit number from the previous iteration. But actually, on my little-endian system that MSB is on the other side. I think I might change my mental model of memory to go right to left as that seems more appropriate (seeing as the instruction is left shift).

Answer (score 2):

The "fun" way:

AArch64 can put a repeating pattern (of any power-of-2 length) into a 64-bit register efficiently, if all the set bits are contiguous inside each repeat.  (That's how it encoded immediates for bitwise boolean instructions like `orr x1, xzr, #0x0303030303030303` = `mov x1, #...`).  This is almost true for your `123` = `0x7b` = `0b1111011`.

Alternatively, `ldr x1, =0x007B007B007B007B` will ask the assembler to do it for you; in this case GAS chooses to put the constant in memory nearby and load it with a PC-relative addressing mode.

**You can reserve space for your array at the same time as you store it to the stack by using a store with a write-back addressing mode** that updates the base register (`sp` in this case) with the offset you subtract.  This is how AArch64 implements stack "push" operations efficiently.  e.g. in a function that needs to save some registers, GCC uses `stp     x29, x30, [sp, -32]!` on function entry to subtract 32 bytes from SP as well as STore that Pair of registers at the bottom of that space.  ([Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:11,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:11,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:11,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:11,startLineNumber:3),source:%27void+bar()%3B%0Aunsigned+long+mul(unsigned+a,+unsigned+b)+%7B%0A++++bar()%3B%0A++++return+a+*+(unsigned+long)b%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:52.43997093127053,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g820,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-Wextra%27,selection:(endColumn:37,endLineNumber:2,positionColumn:37,positionLineNumber:2,selectionStartColumn:9,selectionStartLineNumber:2,startColumn:9,startLineNumber:2),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27ARM64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.56002906872947,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))

So I think this should work. This does assemble but I haven't tried running it.  AArch64's standard calling convention maintains 16-byte stack alignment so this store-pair 16-byte store is aligned.

```
mov     x0, #0x7f007f007f007f
and     x0, x0, #~0x0004000400040004    // construct 0x007B repeating
stp     x0, x0, [sp, -16]!              // push x0 twice

// SP now points at 8 copies of (uint16_t)123, below whatever was on the stack before
```

Loops with `strh` (store 16-bit half-word) are for boring compilers; when hand-writing try to get as much done with as few instructions as possible.  (That's a *general* rule of thumb, not always correlated with performance!  e.g. a wide load that only partially overlaps a previous store may cause a store-forwarding stall if the store was very recent.

Comment: I see, that's super useful to know and much simpler than my half-baked looping construct.